# AuthSub and Blogger

Tags: php, curl, blogger, authsub

I'm trying to retrieve a list of blogs of a given user.
I think I've successivelly authorizated myself with all the token stuff, but when I ask for the list blog, I recieve a 302 moved temporarily.
I'm using curl to send the requests.

In my callback page, I upgrade the token to a session token:

```
$header = array();
$header[] = 'GET /accounts/AuthSubSessionToken HTTP/1.1';
$header[] = 'Authorization: AuthSub token="'.$_GET['token'].'"';

$curl = curl_init('https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubSessionToken');
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
$response = curl_exec( $curl );
```

I obtain this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 15 Jul 2010 20:08:07 GMT
Expires: Thu, 15 Jul 2010 20:08:07 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 39
Server: GSE
```

Ok, now I think I'm ready to data retrieval, I do this:

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'GET /feeds/default/blogs HTTP/1.1';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: AuthSub token="'.$token.'"';
$headers[] = 'Host: www.blogger.com';

$curl = curl_init( 'http://www.blogger.com' );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 80 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
$reply = curl_exec( $curl );
```

But I always receive a 302 moved temporarily.
I've checked I have not enabled safe_mode nor openbasedir to allow CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION work, and I also checked with

```
curl_getinfo( $curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL );
```

what was the last url requested to be sure curl is trying the redirect.

Maybe I did some AuthSub step wrong?

PD: Obviously I ommited the code that extracts the session-token, but I double checked it and I grab the correct part of the header.

Comment: Ok I solved it. I needed to set the url for the third curl_init: http://www.blogger.com/feeds/default/blogs' that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you examine the output of `curl_getinfo($curl);`, do you get a redirect_count? If so: if it's 5 I'd set the maxredirs higher.

If not, I'd set

```
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_STDERR, STDOUT)
```

... and examine it's output.

Maybe it's as simple as setting this (never worked with the blogger interface):

```
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH,true);
```

Comment: The redirect count says 2, so my settings is (for now) enough. Anyway I solved it, it was a problem with the url specified.